# CursorLoader cancels remove animation in RecyclerView

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-cursorloader

I am trying to implement delete operation with swipe in `RecyclerView` with `CursorLoader`. My delete method looks like this:

```
public void removeAt(int position) {
    long id = getItemId(position);
    Uri uriWithId = ContentUris.withAppendedId(mContentUriWithTable, id);

    /** delete in database */
    int rowsDeleted = mContext.getContentResolver().delete(uriWithId, null, null);

    mPendingRunnables.remove(position);
    notifyItemRemoved(position);
}
```

But when I delete a row in database using ContentProvider it refreshes the cursor, rebinds every item and cancels the remove animation. What should I do to save that animation?

Comment: maybe instead of `notifyItemRemoved` you could use `android.support.v7.util.DiffUtil` when loaders gets new data?

Comment: It won't cancel animation?

Comment: see https://medium.com/@nullthemall/diffutil-is-a-must-797502bc1149#.3z3os3sos

Comment: i don't know why but it started to work after i set hasStableIds to true

Comment: but the update will not work i'm afraid

Comment: btw are you using [this](https://gist.github.com/Shywim/127f207e7248fe48400b) adapter?

Comment: no, but why do you think so?

Comment: just a wild guess...